# UWP Before Converter Event

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am looking for an event that takes place before converter.

What I mean is that, I have a custom `UserControl`, and it contains a `ListView`. Its `ListViewItem` has some elements, for example `<TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind IsPlaying, Converter={StaticResource RowColorConverter}, Mode=OneWay} />"`.

This control is used many times. And I have a static `ElementTheme` variable called `CurrentTheme` that is set when that control is loading.

The problem is here. The `Converter` of the `TextBlock` uses that `CurrentTheme` to judge the `Foreground`. However, the `Loading` event isn't always fired before the `Converter`, meaning that the `Foreground` of `TextBlock` will be judge on the old `CurrentTheme`. Correctly speaking, when the `Converter` is firstly loaded, the loading event comes before converter. After it has been loaded, the converter is nearly always called before the loading.

How should I resolve this problem?

---Update---

The converter that I use:

```
class RowColorConverter : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? Helper.GetHighlightBrush() :
                                    PlaylistControl.CurrentTheme == ElementTheme.Dark ? Helper.WhiteSmokeBrush : Helper.BlackBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My code of using: `Interaction.Behaviors`

```
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                            Binding="{x:Bind IsPlaying}"
                            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                            Value="True">
                            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                                PropertyName="Foreground"
                                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ArtistTextBlock}"
                                Value="{StaticResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
                        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                            Binding="{x:Bind IsPlaying}"
                            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                            Value="False">
                            <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                                Binding="{Binding CurrentTheme}"
                                ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                                Value="Dark">
                                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                                    PropertyName="Foreground"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ArtistTextBlock}"
                                    Value="White" />
                            </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>                                
                            <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
                                Binding="{Binding CurrentTheme}"
                                ComparisonCondition="NotEqual"
                                Value="Dark">
                                <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                                    PropertyName="Foreground"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ArtistTextBlock}"
                                    Value="Black" />
                            </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

> UWP Before Converter Event

For your requirement, we suggest you use [`DataTriggerBehavior`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior) that could compare previous value. For example.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="DataTriggerRectangle">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" ComparisonCondition="GreaterThan" Value="50">
            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=DataTriggerRectangle}" PropertyName="Fill" Value="{StaticResource PaleYellowBrush}"/>
        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" ComparisonCondition="LessThanOrEqual" Value="50">
            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=DataTriggerRectangle}" PropertyName="Fill" Value="{StaticResource RoyalBlueBrush}"/>
        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Rectangle>
```

This is official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/tree/master/samples/CS/XAMLBehaviorsSample) that you could refer.

Comment: Which version of `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp` should I use? `Native` or `Managed`?

Comment: Please use Managed version.

Comment: It causes handled exception. Can you go to my updated code area to see where goes wrong?

Comment: @SeakyLuo I checked your code, it looks correct. And I could reproduce your issue with above could, could share a mini project for us?

Comment: Ah my previous comment has a typo. The exception was unhandled. Hope this won't matter. Since you could reproduce it, why are you still requiring a mini project? My code is entangled due to the complexity of my project. I think it is more convenient to download the [whole project](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/tree/master/SMPlayer). I hope you have a list of music files in your PC. The xaml of the code posted above is in **Controls/PlaylistControls.xaml**. The place where that control is used: **NowPlayingPage.xaml** (others are not important). Converter: **MusicConverter.cs**.